# Telegraf parsing “grok” patterns

Tags: logstash-grok, grok, telegraf

I have custom log file and i need to parse it with telegraf parser, this is an example:

> 2018-12-03 13:51:31,682 grafana s.testname EXPERTISE
>   full_access,mentor,employee EXPERTISE_LIST

I created a pattern but gives an error

```
patterns = ["%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}" "%{WORD:grafana}" "%{DATA:user}" "%{DATA:project}" "%{DATA:permissions}" "%{DATA:action}" "%{DATA:additional}"] i
```

done this pattern but its not working

I cant understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: patterns = ["%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}" "%{WORD:grafana}" "%{DATA:user}" "%{DATA:project}" "%{DATA:permissions}" "%{DATA:action}" "%{DATA:additional}"] i done this pattern but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you doing, but your pattern is wrong. You are splitting it into multiple patterns that will never work.
I make a try with your example with this pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:grafana} %{DATA:user} %{DATA:project} %{DATA:permissions} %{WORD:action}
```

And it works.

You can try it [here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: hey @Andreu please answer me this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199853/how-to-create-pattern-to-parse-json-log-in-grok-prometheus